# Option for Simplify command in mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions

What does `Simplify[%[[1]], %[[2]]]` mean in following code?
I mean [[1]] and [[2]] exactly what does refer to?

```
expr = A (2 x1 + B (y1 + y2) + 2 x2)

Collect[expr, B]

Plus @@ {Simplify[%[[1]], %[[2]]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

`%` refers to the last output, which is `A (2 x1 + 2 x2) + A B (y1 + y2)` in your code; and `[[1]]` means the first part of that expression in level 1, which is the first part of `Plus[A (2 x1 + 2 x2), A B (y1 + y2)]`, yields `A (2 x1 + 2 x2)`. Similarly the second part is `A B (y1 + y2)`.

However, the usage of `Simplify` here is treating `A B (y1 + y2)` as an assumption. Perhaps you want `Plus @@ Simplify[{%[[1]], %[[2]]}]`, but this does not produce more useful output than `Simplify[% ]`, just of different form.